# Share AMI to multiple OrganizationARNs boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ami

Currently I am sharing AMI images via OrganizationalArn. However, I am looking to share to multiple OrganizationalArns. I looked into the boto3 documentaiton, but didn't see any examples or information. It appears one can share to many accounts, but not many organizationalArn's.

```
gr_org = [{ 'OrganizationArn' : 'arn:aws:organizations::123456789:organization/o-123456789'}, { 'OrganizationArn' : 'arn:aws:organizations::987654321:organization/o-987654321'}]
ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2',region)
ec2Client.modify_image_attribute(ImageId=amiId,LaunchPermission={'Add': gr_org },
     OperationType='add',DryRun=False)
```

Comment: The documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_image_attribute appears to show that you can do exactly what you are trying to do. Your code looks like it should work as-is. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You are correct, I had a grammatical error in my code, that I didn't paste here. I got it working with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. All you have to do is add another dict in 'Add', like

```
    LaunchPermissions = {
[
'Add': [
  {OrganizationArn: org1},
  {OrganizationArn: org2}]
]}
```

The other way you can do this is to use `'OrganizationArns = [org1, org2]`

AWS initially had LaunchPermissions parameter only but that was a bit cumbersome as you have to create a list of dicts for 'Add' or 'Remove' operation.

Now, you can also use parameters like OrganizationArns = [] directly, something like:

```
modify_image_attribute(Attribute='launchPermission', OrganizationArns=[org1, org2], ImageId=amiId)
```